# Error with Out-File: Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Tags: powershell, output, pipeline

The following code line is giving me a pipeline error:

```
$user.name + "|" + $user.DisplayName | Out-File $output -Append
"Managing Group: " | + $_.name + "|" +`
" Group Description: " +  ($_.description -replace "`r`n", "  ") | Out-File $output -Append
```

I have tried replacing the part of code with:

```
(& { process{$_.description -replace "`r`n", "  "}} )
(foeach-object{$_.description -replace "`r`n", "  "} )
%{$_.description -replace "`r`n", "  "}
```

But nothing seems to fix the error.

Error:

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline. At
>   C:\AD-User.MonitorAll.ps1:92 char:82
>   +                 " Group Description: " +  ($_.description -replace "`r`n", "  ")  <<<<  | Out-File $output -Append
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

UPDATE:

my issue was I was missing the " " over the | after "Managing Group: "

```
$user.name + "|" + $user.DisplayName | Out-File $output -Append
          "Managing Group: " + "|" + $_.name + "|" +`
            " Group Description: " +  ($_.description -replace "`r`n", "  ") | Out-File $output -Append
```

Comment: I split the line of code because I get fairly long list for "Managing groups" so I wanted the name and display name on it's own line -FYI

Comment: Are you trying to output this with `|` separator? If so there are much cleaner methods.

Comment: Yes I am using the | as a separator

Comment: Yes I just did. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please dont update titles with "Update" or "Answered" type text. Marking questioned as answers serves the same purpose.

Comment: Ok I will stop that. I also answered my question and can't check mark it till a couple hours later so I wanted to make sure someone didn't answer it after.

Answer (score 1):

You're not quoting the `|` in the second line. Also, try to avoid backticks to escape newlines. I've rewritten it to use subexpressions `$()`.

```
"$($user.name)|$($user.DisplayName)" | Out-File $output -Append
"Managing Group: | $($_.name)| Group Description: $($_.description -replace "`r`n", "  ")" | Out-File $output -Append
```

Comment: Ya I caught that error. Thanks :)
and I am not too familiar with your format of $($_.name). Also when you mean newlines with backticks do you mean when code is ran? I've been taught that the backticks are for newlines in the powershell software just so that long line of codes are more easily displayed in program only.

Comment: Subexpressions `$()` like $($user.name) can be used inside a string to get dynamic content. Powershell will process all subexpressions and replace them with the result in the string. That way, you can write the string as one part instead of `"this"+$user.name+"that"`. On the second line, you use `+'`(backtick) to split the 2nd command so it wouldn't be so long. The backtick simply escapes(ignores) the hidden `\n` (linebreak) in your script. If you made a typo and got a whitespace after the backtick, then your script would fail, so try to avoid using backticks to make lines easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I missed " " over one of my | separators. Thanks @Shawn Melton. The minute you said " | separator" I looked and realized I had a typo.